# diferencia entre una hora HH:MM con moment

Tags: javascript, php, momentjs

Deseo saber la diferencia entre una hora `HH:MM` de inicio y termino.

Tengo el siguiente código, pero me gustaría que la diferencia la muestre `3.5`. Con este ejemplo obtengo `3` pero debería obtener `3.5` ya que tengo 30 minutos y así llegaría a `4`
Esto lo tengo en `JAVASCRIPT` tambien me gustaria la forma de hacerlo en `PHP`

```js
response = {
  startTime: '09:30',
  endTime: '13:00'
};

var momentStartTime = moment(response.startTime, 'hh:mm');
var momentEndTime = moment(response.endTime, 'hh:mm');

console.log(momentEndTime.diff(momentStartTime, 'minutes') / 60);

var html = 'Tiempo Diferencia : <br/>';
html += 'Diferencia (hours): ' + momentEndTime.diff(momentStartTime, 'hours') + '<br/>';

$('#output').html(html);
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <p id="output">
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no sé si está mal formulada, porque en la pregunta dice que que te gustaría que la muestre redondeada pero al parecer no lo quieres.

Comment: @JeanGotopo Corregui un poco la pregunta. Gracias

Comment: Pero, por qué no pones como lo pusiste en el console.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola es simple solo calcule la diferencia en minutos y divida entre 60

```js
response = {
  startTime: '06:30',
  endTime: '10:00'
};

var momentStartTime = moment(response.startTime, 'hh:mm');
var momentEndTime = moment(response.endTime, 'hh:mm');

var html = 'Tiempo Diferencia : <br/>';
html += 'Diferencia (hours): ' + momentEndTime.diff(momentStartTime, 'minutes') / 60 + '<br/>';

$('#output').html(html);
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <p id="output">
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

ahora en php

```
$startTime = new DateTime('06:30');
$endTime = new DateTime('10:00');
$diff = $startTime->diff($endTime);
$differenceInHours = $diff->h . ($diff->i > 0 ? "." . ($diff->i * 10 / 6) . "" : "");
```

Ahora esta salida puede ser confusa, xq ver 3.50 puede ser interpretado como 3 horas y 50 min, creo que la mejor forma es dejarlo 3.30 para lograr esto es cambiar

PHP:

```
$startTime = new DateTime('06:30');
$endTime = new DateTime('10:00');
$diff = $startTime->diff($endTime);
$differenceInHours = $diff->h . ($diff->i > 0 ? "." . $diff->i : "");
```

JS:

```js
response = {
      startTime: '06:30',
      endTime: '10:00'
    };

    var momentStartTime = moment(response.startTime, 'hh:mm');
    var momentEndTime = moment(response.endTime, 'hh:mm');

var hoursDiff = momentEndTime.diff(momentStartTime, 'hours');
var minutesDiff = momentEndTime.diff(momentStartTime, 'minutes') % 60;
    var html = 'Tiempo Diferencia : <br/>';
    html += 'Diferencia (hours): ' + hoursDiff
    + 
    (minutesDiff > 0 ? "." + minutesDiff : "")
    + '<br/>';
    
      $('#output').html(html);
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <html>

    <body>
      <p id="output">
      </p>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Saludos

Comment: Estimado me encontre con el siguiente error `$start = '08:45';
$end   = '09:50';` obtengo  `1.8.3333333333333`